# rake db:migration not working on travis-ci build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rake, travis-ci

I'm trying to build my Ruby on Rails project from github on Travis-CI, but I 'm running into a migration problem. It runs a rake task for migration, but it complains about the same migration step after that.

It follows my .travis.yml file:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 1.9.2
before_script:
  - "rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test"
```

And here's the build output:

```
1Using worker: ruby4.worker.travis-ci.org:travis-ruby-3
2
3
4
5$ cd ~/builds
6
7
8$ git clone --depth=100 --quiet git://github.com/rafaelportela/bacilo.git rafaelportela/bacilo
9
10
11
12$ cd rafaelportela/bacilo
13
14$ git checkout -qf 7553b7351b7a642e39ea7b55204de6cd4f320c36
15
16
17$ export TRAVIS_RUBY_VERSION=1.9.2
18
19$ rvm use 1.9.2
20Using /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
21
22$ ruby --version
23ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
24
25$ gem --version
261.8.17
27
28
29$ export BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/home/vagrant/builds/rafaelportela/bacilo/Gemfile
30
31$ bundle install
32Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
33Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
34Installing i18n (0.6.0) 
35Installing multi_json (1.3.4) 
36Installing activesupport (3.2.2) 
37Installing builder (3.0.0) 
38Installing activemodel (3.2.2) 
39Installing erubis (2.7.0) 
40Installing journey (1.0.3) 
41Installing rack (1.4.1) 
42Installing rack-cache (1.2) 
43Installing rack-test (0.6.1) 
44Installing hike (1.2.1) 
45Installing tilt (1.3.3) 
46Installing sprockets (2.1.3) 
47Installing actionpack (3.2.2) 
48Installing mime-types (1.18) 
49Installing polyglot (0.3.3) 
50Installing treetop (1.4.10) 
51Installing mail (2.4.4) 
52Installing actionmailer (3.2.2) 
53Installing arel (3.0.2) 
54Installing tzinfo (0.3.33) 
55Installing activerecord (3.2.2) 
56Installing activeresource (3.2.2) 
57Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) with native extensions 
58Installing coffee-script-source (1.3.1) 
59Installing execjs (1.3.1) 
60Installing coffee-script (2.2.0) 
61Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
62Installing json (1.7.0) with native extensions 
63Installing rdoc (3.12) 
64Installing thor (0.14.6) 
65Installing railties (3.2.2) 
66Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
67Installing orm_adapter (0.0.7) 
68Installing warden (1.1.1) 
69Installing devise (2.0.4) 
70Installing jquery-rails (2.0.2) 
71Installing pg (0.13.2) with native extensions 
72Using bundler (1.1.3) 
73Installing rails (3.2.2) 
74Installing sass (3.1.16) 
75Installing sass-rails (3.2.5) 
76Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6) with native extensions 
77Installing uglifier (1.2.4) 
78Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
79Post-install message from rdoc:
80Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
81
82<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
83 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
84 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
85>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
86
87
88$ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
89==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
90-- create_table(:users)
91   -> 0.0174s
92-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
93   -> 0.0017s
94-- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
95   -> 0.0010s
96==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrated (0.0239s) =====================================
97
98
99$ bundle exec rake
100You have 1 pending migrations:
101  20120508052346 DeviseCreateUsers
102Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
103
104
105Done. Build script exited with: 1
```

I'd appreciate any suggestion! =]

Comment: Hi rafael, I guess you're running your test-environment on a sqlite3 db with in-memory usage, right?
Because I am struggling with the same problem combined of:

- **travis-ci**

- **sqlite** {database: "**:memory:**"}


I am also wondering, because this setting is also recommended / given as an example in the [travis-ci doc](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#SQLite3).

Comment: this works but you may need to alter it to  `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[This blog post](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-test-your-rails-application-with-travis-ci-on-different-database-engines-1220.html) helped me tremendously when I was trying to get my Rails 3.2 app working with Travis CI, and write a `.travis.yml` file that actually worked.  Here's mine for your reference, so hope it helps:

**.travis.yml**

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 1.9.2
  - 1.9.3
env:
  - DB=sqlite
  - DB=mysql
  - DB=postgresql
script: 
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
  - bundle exec rspec spec/
before_script:
  - mysql -e 'create database my_app_test'
  - psql -c 'create database my_app_test' -U postgres
bundler_args: --binstubs=./bundler_stubs
```

Comment: Thanks. How did you manage the database.yml for travis? and also can you please post the bundler_stubs file contents?

Comment: @Pratick, hopefully you should get your answers from [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11156627/567863).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of running `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` run `rake db:test:prepare` instead.

This is because `rake db:migrate` will run *all* the migrations against your test database, which could take a very long time if you had a lot of migrations. The `db:test:prepare` task will not do that, instead it will just set up the test database with the schema from `db/schema.rb`.

Give that a shot and see if that works.

Comment: This is generally a bad idea. You want your test environment to find problems that could potentially happen in production. In production, you will be running migrations, not loading your schema from your db/schema.rb. In order to find potential problems with migrations that could happen on production, it is better to run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that fixed the problem for me was running:
`rake db:schema:load` instead of `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`