# Database issues when using RSpec for testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rspec, rake, rails-migrations

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project and trying to get RSpec working so i can write some tests.  I run the following command:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/
```

to run my test. I then get the error

```
 Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test' to resolve this issue.
```

so then i run

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

and get the following error

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `rake db:test:prepare` ?

Comment: Try creating an empty test db and run the migrations again. You seem to have a conflict with the index.

Comment: @DamienRoche Thanks! If you want you can move that to the answer so I can accpet it, and give you some Reputation points!

Comment: Great to hear! Will do.

Answer (score 1):

The error is misleading. You should never run migrations directly on your test db. Run:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Answer (score 0):

This post may be helpful depending on your Rails version: [Rake db:test:prepare task deleting data in development database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156627/rake-dbtestprepare-task-deleting-data-in-development-database)

Rails 3.2.9 may solve your issue.